# Combine/match/merge vectors by row names

Tags: r

I have a vector of variable names and several matrices with single rows.

I want to create a new matrix. The new matrix is created by match/merge the row names of the matrices with single rows.

Example:

A vector of variable names

```
Complete_names <- c("D","C","A","B")
```

Several matrices with single rows

```
Matrix_1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3),3,1)
rownames(Matrix_1) <- c("D","C","B")

Matrix_2 <- matrix(c(4,5,6),3,1)
rownames(Matrix_1) <- c("A","B","C")
```

Desired output:

```
Desired_output <- matrix(c(1,2,NA,3,NA,6,4,5),4,2)
rownames(Desired_output) <- c("D","C","A","B")

 [,1] [,2]
D    1   NA
C    2    6
A   NA    4
B    3    5
```

I know there are several similar postings like this, but those previous answers do not work perfectly for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers offered by Julius Vainora and achimneyswallow work well, but just to exactly obtain the desired output I want:

```
temp <- merge(Matrix_1, Matrix_2, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)
temp$Row.names <- factor(temp$Row.names, levels=Complete_names)
temp <- temp[order(temp$Row.names),]
rownames(temp) <- temp[,1]
Desired_output <- as.matrix(temp[,-1])

  V1.x V1.y
D    1   NA
C    2    6
A   NA    4
B    3    5
```

Answer (score 1):

The main job can be done with `merge`, returning a data frame:

```
merge(Matrix_1, Matrix_2, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)
#   Row.names V1.x V1.y
# 1         A   NA    4
# 2         B    3    5
# 3         C    2    6
# 4         D    1   NA
```

Depending on your purposes you may then further modify names or get rid of `Row.names`.